# Jenkins Throttle concurrent build < 7 count issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have requirement to allow concurrent builds in a single Jenkins job in single slave node.

So I have enabled the throttle concurrent build option and post which I am able to do concurrent builds.  But If I give max no of concurrent builds 7 or more than 7, then it always process 6 builds at a time and 7th build goes on wait status.

Is there any max no limitation in this scenario?

[image]

Comment: You said you have these all tied to a single agent node... Does that node have 10 executors?

Comment: Since I don't have administrator access, I couldn't able to check at the moment.   **xxxxxxx is missing the Overall/Administer permission**

Comment: Verified its 6 executors configured.  This helps really.

Comment: Well, there you go. :)

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the total number of executors in jenkins slave node server will resolve this - as Rob suggested.